# Custom REST API endpoint - Consumer is not authorized to access %resources - Magento_Indexer::Indexer

Tags: magento2, rest-api, indexer, acl

I'm trying to expose the `getLatestUpdated()` method of the `Indexer` class through the REST API.  The endpoint is getting an auth token and all that - I can use protected endpoints no problem.  What resources should I have requested or how can I give my extension permission to use the resource?

Here is what my `webapi.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/GetIndexerInfo/id/:id" method="GET">
        <service class="MyCompany\GetIndexerInfo\Api\GetIndexerInfoInterface" method="getInfo"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Indexer::Indexer"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that, despite already having a good key, because this was new functionality, it seemed to require re-authorizing my key (getting a new token).

Answer (score 2):

- `ref.` Required. Referenced resource.
- Valid values are `self`, `anonymous`, or a Magento resource, such as
  `Magento_Customer::group`.

  ---

  ```
   <route url="/V1/customers/:id" method="PUT">
          <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
          <resources>
              <resource ref="Magento_Customer::manage"/>
          </resources>
   </route>
  ```

Now open **acl.xml** file where `ref` Magento resource, `Magento_Customer::manage` is defined

[image]

And this resources are visible under the Magento 2 admin **System > Permissions > User Roles** area. When we click on the Add New Role button or access to a role.

like this,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to give permission to your module and check.

1. Create below file in your module.
   File: app/code/Neo/Yourmodulename/etc/acl.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
       <acl>
           <resources>
               <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                   <resource id="Neo_Yourmodulename::helloworld" title="Hello World" sortOrder="51">
                   </resource>
               </resource>
           </resources>
       </acl>
   </config>
   ```
2. Flush Magento cache.
3. For more details click here: [Magento 2 Admin ACL Access Control Lists](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-acl-access-control-lists.html)

Comment: ::helloworld - is this a class name or the name of the method invoked by the api?

Comment: This did not change anything unfortunately.  I did go into integrations and add permission to my user.